# ASP.NET: Populate a class from form postback?

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I was wondering if there is a tool / framework or something similar that would allow me to populate a class' properties with the items from the FORM posted values?

Rather than doing

```
    class.ID = Response.Form["ID"];
```

etc

I currently use automapper for tranforming from some objects to another..

Maybe its possible to do this?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

To confirm the technology is winform (ASP.NET) not MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC this is built in. Put in a class in your Controllers Action parameters and it will be implicit.

Guess you might be using .NET forms though?

Comment: Yes exactly, i have been using MVC also and yes you are correct now i am looking for something similar for winforms

Comment: It is not something I have ever come across unfortunately. I would haev thought it would be difficult due to the nature of the page life cycle but you could potentially have some custom parser in the page load. Not sure it would really assist you that much. If you do find something though please share as would be interesting for some of my legacy stuff.